# How to add elements to a queue when the queue is already full and some values are then removed?

Tags: queue

I have created a queue of size 5. I inserted 5 values into the queue (1,2,3,4,5). now my front value is at the index 0 and my rear value is pointing at the index 4(the last position of my queue). Now I removed one element from the queue and so, my queue now has only (2,3,4,5) in it. now my queue is not full, since it has a free position in it. Only 4 values are filled and one value is removed. How could I enter a new value to that empty location in my queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

**For Enqueue :**

```
rear = (rear+1)%MAX_SIZE;
```

So now when rear is at end position and there is free space in front then the following code will start returning the index in circular way.

**For Dequeue :**

```
front = (front+1)%MAX_SIZE;
```

Similar in case of dequeue.

**Note :**

You have to put condition of if the array is empty or full in your code.
Also if front and rear comes at same position than that means array is now empty and you have to assign both of them empty position index.

Answer (score -1):

set this condition
 1. If ( COUNT = MAX ) then
        a.  Display  “Queue overflow”;
        b.  Return;
    2.  Otherwise
        a.  If ( REAR = MAX ) then
            i.  REAR := 1;
        b.  Otherwise
            i.  REAR := REAR + 1;
        c.  QUEUE(REAR) := ITEM;
        d.  COUNT := COUNT + 1;
    3.  Return;